# no muestra mi CAPTCHA google de mi app web - Uncaught Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, spring-security, captcha

Tengo una aplicación web, genero mi `.war` para deployarlo en un tomcat 9 de mi maquina, al abrir mi aplicación en un explorador no se muestra el captcha, agregue el dominio en la configuración del captcha, agregué dos linea en mi `.jsp` para mostrar el captcha.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="clave-asignada"></div>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

Hice un ejemplo sencillo en un .html con solo mostrar el captcha y me lo muestra sin problemas, ya que subí ese `.html` en un xammp.